# Monitor if service on VM is up integrated in Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, network-monitoring

I have a VM running a service which I connect to from my application. Let's say it's a MongoDB service.

I would like to monitor with one of Azure's existing tools if the MongoDB service is up. The easiest way to accomplish this seems to be a simple tcpconnect on the MongoDB port (27017), and if it fails say 3 times, send an alert. I can't figure out how to configure this with either:

- Operation Management Suite (OMS)
- Log Analytics
- Network Watcher.

Is it possible to configure this kind of monitoring/alerts with these services? Or is there another service that is managed by Azure which I can use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time researching and trying to find some answer, since I haven't set this up personally.

Easiest I think would be to configure [Log Analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/log-analytics/) to read any custom logs your application creates and let it ingest them. Then create a log search with an alert that either alerts you or automatically run some custom logic.

I could not find any way to monitor if a port is open, e.g. how you can do with "psping www.google.com:80" for TCP 80.

In other words, to me seems easiest would be to:

1. Set up [custom log collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-data-sources-custom-logs) in log analytics
2. Create a [log search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-log-searches) for the events you want to monitor
3. Set up [an alert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-alerts-creating) for the custom search

Comment: The purpose of the alert is to detect when a service my app uses (like MongoDB) goes down, as quickly as possible. If my app is quiet for a while no logs would be created, so no alert would be fired.

I'm really scatching my head about this. It seems such a basic thing. Am I possibily missing something and is the way I want to check if my dependency is up not the recommended way to do so?